# HttpWebRequest.Headers are missing some headers

Tags: c#, .net, header, httpwebrequest

I iam working on a tool that let users check their API. One of the features is to show the actual send request headers.

Iam having trouble getting these headers though as the Headers property doesnt seem to include them all. I tried looking at tracelisteners but these seem to be more oriented to debugging and the config is global so it applies to all webrequests send by the app which is not what I want.

When I run this code on net48 (in core I seem to get 0 headers back):

```
// Create a new 'HttpWebRequest' Object to the mentioned URL.
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
// Assign the response object of 'HttpWebRequest' to a 'HttpWebResponse' variable.
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("\nThe HttpHeaders are \n\n\tName\t\tValue\n{0}",myHttpWebRequest.Headers);
```

I get the following output

```
The HttpHeaders are

    Name            Value
Host: www.microsoft.com
```

However in fiddler and with trace listeners I see these headers:

```
Host: www.contoso.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Why can't I see the Connection header?

Answer (score 0):

Now I see there is some redirecting going on. WebRequest seems to only show the headers send in the LAST request which didn't had the Connection header.